# Install different versions of NodeJS

Tags: node.js, version

Is it possible to have different versions of [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) installed on the same machine?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

There are several node managers which you can use to achieve this, but the most popular are:

- [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm)
- [n](https://github.com/visionmedia/n)

Comment: N seems really awesome, but it doesn't seem to override my running version of node.js. Do you use n, and know how to get it to pre-empt your originally installed version of node?

Comment: I actually use NVM at the moment, and I can always roll back to whatever version of Node I want and make is the default. N should have that functionality also though.

Comment: For Windows, use [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows), which comes with an installer and is well maintained. (It's also mentioned in this SOF question: [multiple-versions-of-node-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399621/multiple-versions-of-node-on-windows)).

Comment: NVM has a possibility to set node version in the `.nvmrc` file, I cannot find this feature in N docs, so NVM wins for me

Answer (score 15):

I use nave. https://github.com/isaacs/nave

```
> npm install -g nave
> nave use 0.4.12 # starts a subshell with 0.4.12 at the head of the path
> node --version
v0.4.12
> exit # go back to the original shell
> nave use 0.6.5
> node --version
v0.6.5
> nave usemain
```

Note that the first time you need a version, it will be downloaded and compiled for you.

Comment: Nave requires bash. It will probably never work on Windows, or other systems lack a native Bourne Again Shell. https://github.com/isaacs/nave#compatibility

Comment: You can also create **named environments**. E.g  `nave use foobar` will ask you what version of node to associate with `foobar`.Once it is created, it can be switched to using the same command.

Answer (score 6):

If you need something simple, the `n` utility is just for you.

Install it (use `sudo` prefix in commands if required):

```
npm -g install n
```

then :

```
npm cache clean -f
```

(don't be scared about the warning)

then just ask `n` to (download if required and) use the version you specify. For instance:

```
n 0.11.13
```

Et voilà !

Should you install multiple versions, you'll be able to switch between them. See the [n page](https://github.com/visionmedia/n) for details.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow simple approach here

**step1:**

```
 $ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.11.1/install.sh | bash
```

**step2:**

```
 $ source ~/.profile
```

**step3:** list the latest versions of node

```
 $ nvm ls-remote
```

**step4:**

```
  $  nvm install 7.10.0
```

**step5:** Create alias as default for node version

```
$ nvm alias default 7.10.0
```

**step6:**

```
$node --version
```

that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Windows users check out `nvmw` [here](https://github.com/hakobera/nvmw).

You can go quite a long way down trying to install some of the other versions listed before realising there's no Windows support.

e.g. on the page for `nave`

> It will probably never work on Windows, or other systems lack a native
>   Bourne Again Shell. Sorry.

Comment: nvmw seems to be not supported anymore: "SORRY, nvmw is no longer maintained. If someone wants to keep maintained, contact me by email or twitter."

Answer (score 0):

The best option is node version manager [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) is very simple to install and you can change from one version to another with a simple `nvm use` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NVM - Node Version Manager, Supports both Windows and Mac.

It has all the instructions of how to install and use it.

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

These will be independent installs so you will need to install packages in each versions.