# How can I use two different node versions for two different Laravel projects?

Tags: node.js, laravel, ubuntu-16.04

I have two Laravel projects one will work with `gulp` and another will work with `web pack`. And now the problem is `gulp` is not working with latest version of `node` and `webpack` needs only latest version of node.I'm like confused how do I deal with this?

Can two different node versions be used for this two Laravel projects? Is it possible to install two versions of node in Ubuntu? How to make these two projects work with their respective node versions?

Can anybody suggest some solution for this?

Comment: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: And this is a good case to use .nvmrc files https://github.com/creationix/nvm#nvmrc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install different versions of NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455290/install-different-versions-of-nodejs)

Comment: @FabioAntunes : Thank you for the reference. I'm checking the docs.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at Docker
https://www.docker.com/

with docker you can build & run different VM with the configurtion you need.
and it's really easy tu use

hope it help

Comment: I tried installing docker it was giving some error could not able to fix it. :(

Comment: well you can create a ticket about your docker issue :), but nvm also is a greate solution

Comment: Yeah will do that then :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem. Installing `libpng-dev` solves problem in my ubuntu17.10.

```
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
```

and did a full reset by running the following commands

```
 rm -rf node_modules
 rm package-lock.json yarn.lock
 npm cache clear --force
 npm install
 npm run dev
```

this is the reference link : https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/1072