# Multiple versions of node on windows

Tags: node.js, angular

I currently have the following versions installed my windows machine.

node : v7.3.0 
npm  : 3.10.10
@angular/cli : 1.4.2

I would like to install latest versions of the above and be able to switch accordingly. To my knowledge installation of node governs that. If I need to install latest npm and angular cli then i would need to install the latest version of node. Please do correct me if I am wrong. Can i globally install the latest version of nodejs. Once I install that could i switch between the node versions. I presume switching between the node versions would take care to use the appropriate npm and cli.

Comment: There's a project called `nvm-windows` I've used before: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows

Comment: So if I  install latest version of node and then say nvm use the new version and then install  latest version of npm and angular cli, would switching between the node versions take the appropriate versions of npm and cli. So i believe when i install npm and angular cli they would be tied to that specific nodejs version installation. I am looking for that kind of ability to switch

Comment: According to the documentation: "Please note that any global npm modules you may have installed are not shared between the various versions of node.js you have installed." So yes, it sounds like they will be tied to the version of npm

Comment: Perfect that what i was looking for

Comment: I have installed node version v8.11.2. when i run nvm list i expected it to show both the versions but it shows only 7.3.0.  When I run node -v it shows 8.11.0. if i execute nvm use 7.3.0 then i get a message node v7.3.0 (64-bit) is not installed. I am confused

Comment: Angular cli has nothing to do with your node version.

Comment: I am not referring to angular-cli version. I am currently having node version 7.3.0 and 8.11.0 installed

Comment: is there any particular sequence of installing different versions of node?

Answer (score 53):

This is achievable via various version managers.

For Windows, take a look at [NVM for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows).

For macOS or Linux (not your OS, I see, but for others reading), I like [n](https://github.com/tj/n), and [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) is also widely used.

Comment: I've kept the mac and linux info as it's likely that other people reading find this by searching for similar info. Windows is on top though. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: So if I install latest version of node and then say nvm use the new version and then install latest version of npm and angular cli, would switching between the node versions take the appropriate versions of npm and cli. So i believe when i install npm and angular cli they would be tied to that specific nodejs version installation. I am looking for that kind of ability to switch

Comment: I would add, to answer the other parts of his question. Changing your node version does not effect your angular cli version in any way shape or form.

Comment: Nvm on windows not work with latests versions (10.x.x) of nodejs

Comment: for linux users: There is also a node [plugin](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-nodejs) for [asdf-vm](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf)

Answer (score 41):

[***nvm-windows***](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases) let's you do that. Before installing ***nvm-windows***, please uninstall all `Node` versions from your computer.

To install any `Node` version, type in **command prompt** `nvm install [node version]`, like for example:

- `nvm install 10.16.0`
- `nvm install 6.11.0`

---

`nvm list` lists all `Node` versions you installed:

- 10.16.0
- 6.11.0

---

```
nvm use 6.11.0
```

or

```
nvm use [version name]
```

and you will be prompted by a windows pop up to allow ***nvm-windows*** to use/switch to a particular `Node` version.

Answer (score 0):

I set my node version default like this: `nvm alias default <version>`

Answer (score 0):

For context, I needed to run different node versions across different terminals on windows, and found that nvm-windows does not support it because of the way it works as per Gabriel's answer on top.

Found this wonderful work on github - https://github.com/davfive/nvm-session and all credits to the creator, for building a simple workaround for this. The steps to get this working are clearly explained in the README of the repository, and helped me solve my problem!

However, I believe it requires you to use git-bash/any such bash-supported terminals on windows to get this working!