# Unable to debug Angular with WebStorm

Tags: angular, debugging, webstorm

I have an Angular application (Angular 2) that I can launch without issue from WebStorm, however when I try and set breakpoints none of them are ever hit. WebStorm reports that the debugger is attached and that webpack has compiled successfully. I open my browser to localhost:4200 and my app loads fine, it's just that none of my breakpoints are hit. I also have the JetBrains IDE extension installed but my understanding was that it wasn't necessary anymore.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work after much trial and error.

1. I setup a debug configuration using the WebStorm "npm" template (screen capture below). You can ignore the Script parameter in the screenshot as this is simply an alias (located in `package.json`) pointing to a JSON file that contains proxies for external API endpoints (DEV, Production, Stage, etc)
2. From here I could launch my Angular application and webpack would compile everything
3. At this point my application would run normally but no breakpoints would be hit. Then I installed the JetBrains IDE Support Chrome Extension. Once installed, I right clicked on the extension and chose "Inspect in WebStorm" option. At that point the WebStorm IDE opened a second DEBUG window named "localhost:4200". The any breakpoints I had set were hit whenever I triggered them.

So they key was the JetBrains IDE support Chrome Extension. It was my understanding that this was no longer needed in the newer versions of WebStorm but it appears that to debug my Angular application it is still required. It can be downloaded from the Chrome Extension store [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji).

I hope this helps someone else out because it drove me nuts for the longest time.

[image: NPM Debug Configuration]
**NPM Debug Configuration**

[image: Webpack compiling]
**Webpack compiling**

[image: Debug window at http://localhost:4200]
**Debug window at http://localhost:4200**

Comment: *JetBrains IDE Support Chrome Extension* is NOT required since 2019.x (moreover, it's not reliable, debugging works much better without it). The key point is the *JavaScript Debug* run configuration that was created and started for you when choosing *Inspect in WebStorm* - it is indeed required for client-side debugging. But you can easily create it manually (moreover, WebStorm normally auto-creates it for you when opening Angular cli app). See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.2/angular.html#angular_running_and_debugging

Comment: @lena What you are saying doesn't apply to my situation.I am running Angular via the NPM CLI. You are talking about setting up a JavaScript debug configuration. They are not the same thing.

Comment: sure they aren't. Angular CLI apps are usually run with npm, this is nothing unusual in your setup - you need running scripts to build the application and start the dev server; but you need using  *JavaScript debug* configuration to debug it.

Comment: It works which is more than I can say for WebStorm's documentation

Answer (score 17):

Step 1 : Click on the top right corner drop down > edit configuration

[image]

Step 2: Under the run debug configurations> hit the `+` symbol and select Javascript Debug

[image]

Step 3: Make sure you have created new profile under Javascript debug (In my case profile name is Angular Applicaiton > URL: http://localhost:4200

[image]

Step 4: Once everything is set properly. Make sure you select the proper profile from the dropdown like below

[image]

Step 5: Make sure you are serving your application via ng s in terminal then click on the Debug button (Remember do not hit the play green button). Press the Red bug button as per above screenshot..

It should now open the localhost:4200 in new window

Note: Make sure you added enough breakpoints in your ts file to debug it

Now your breakpoints will definitely work.

Comment: I tried the steps you listed. My debug icon is a green bug as opposed to a red bug. Dose that make a difference? In any case when I clicked the green bug it opened an empty chrome window and then after a few seconds a message appeared in webstorm saying `Waiting for connection to localhost:63276`

Comment: May be the color depends on the theme color scheme you have. Did you follow my screen shot and set the URL to http://localhost:4200. If so once everything is set then you have to choose the profile from the drop down . Updated my answer with more steps

Comment: Thank you! Webstorm detects the configuration of an angular project when you're on te project folder. When you're in the parent folder of the project (1 layer above the project) no config is loaded. The steps above helped me to create a config for this situation.

Answer (score 5):

I know that the answer is already here but may be someone may find it helpful

Acording to the documentation

```
 Debugging of Angular applications is only supported with Node.js version 16 and earlier.
```

So check the Node version, if it is higher, the debugger won't stop at the breakpoint
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/angular.html

Comment: so, how can we do with node > 16?

Comment: @G.M https://stackoverflow.com/a/60402728/929209

Comment: I actually got it working with node v18.19.0 by using a `JavaScript Debug` configuration. No need to install a different node version

Answer (score 4):

Worked for me I hope it will help:
1.run with debug mode
2.Hold Ctrl+Shift and click this URL ex.(http://localhost:4200)

WebStorm starts a debugging session with an automatically generated Angular Application configuration of the type JavaScript Debug as written in official documentation
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/angular.html#angular_running_and_debugging_debug

Answer (score 1):

The other answers help, but the key for me was having the right default browser (I use Firefox by default, which is not supported, so CTRL+SHIFT was not launching a new Chrome instance).
[image]

To start an Angular debugging session:

- Click the "play" button for your normal `ng serve` config
- CTRL + SHIFT click the http://localhost:4200 link in the output
- **IMPORTANT: Make sure a NEW Chrome window opens (this will be linked to the debugger)**
- Ensure the autogenerated JavaScript Debug run config is running in debug mode