How to debug Angular 17 or 18 application with WebStrom
Hello everyone I am having problem with Debug.I tried the guide from JetBrains website but Debug is not working please help me.
I translated my words using google translate
I tried debugging using google chrome but I want to debug through WebStromI called the debugger function and You can see the debugger running through Chrome
I translated my words using google translate

Set URL to http://localhost:4200 (or the URL your app runs on) under the Run > Edit Configurations. You need to add this under Javascript debug. You can set breakpoints inn your TypeScript files by clicking next to the line numbers where you want to pause the execution OR use debugger Keyword in your code where you want to stop execution. Click the Debug button (green bug icon) to start debugging.

I did as you said but it didn't work please help me if possible.

How can I add an image in a static file to a comment? For me to show you?

You can just edit your question and attach images based on what you are seeing.

This answer is for your reference. Hope this helps, if not, I can guide here more
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58741749/7226984
